# Приложение андроид останавливается при нажатии на кнопку отправить данные через http запросы

Tags: android, http, android-asynctask

Я пишу приложение на андроид, в котором я должен авторизироваться на сервере и отправить туда кое-какие данные.
Ниже часть моего кода для авторизации и отправки данных

```
package com.example.sanzharaubakir.fin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpEntity;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpResponse;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.NameValuePair;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.ClientProtocolException;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.HttpClient;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.methods.HttpPost;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.util.EntityUtils;

/**
 * Created by sanzharaubakir on 26.07.16.
 */
public class auth extends Activity {
    EditText login;
    EditText pswd;
    Button ok;
    MyTask task;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.authorization);
        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
        login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login);
        pswd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pswd);
        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                task = new MyTask();
                task.execute();
            }
        });
    }



    public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            sendData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        }
    }
    public void sendData()
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Данные отправлены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://144.76.29.144:8001/documents/api/login");
        try {
            String log = login.getText().toString();
            String psw = pswd.getText().toString();
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", log));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", psw));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            String tk = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            if (responseCode == 200)
            {
                SharedPreferences sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor e = sPref.edit();
                e.putString("token", tk);
                e.apply();
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                String info = intent.getStringExtra("d");
                try {
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost Post = new HttpPost("http://144.76.29.144:8001");
                    List<NameValuePair> ValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                    ValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", info));
                    ValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", tk));

                    Post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(ValuePairs,"UTF-8"));
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(Post);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    info = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity,"UTF-8");
                    //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Данные отправлены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    //toast.show();

                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();

                } catch (IOException ex) {

                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else {
                //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Неверный логин или пароль", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                //toast.show();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
}
```

вот код XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/login"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Password"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/pswd"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ok"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Log in"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

При нажатии на кнопку log in приложение останавливается. 
Вот что пишется в Log

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                                                                            Process: com.example.sanzharaubakir.fin, PID: 22007
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
                                                                                at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:327)
                                                                                at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:92)
                                                                                at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:241)
                                                                                at com.example.sanzharaubakir.fin.auth.sendData(auth.java:73)
                                                                                at com.example.sanzharaubakir.fin.auth$MyTask.doInBackground(auth.java:60)
                                                                                at com.example.sanzharaubakir.fin.auth$MyTask.doInBackground(auth.java:55)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

переводится как `ОперацииССетьюВГлавномПотокеОшибка`, из чего ,очевидно, следует, что нельзя проводить операции с сетью в главном потоке. Вынесите работу с сетью в background-поток

---

Теперь у вас проблема наоборот - вы пытаетесь работать с UI в background потоке. ТАк делать тоже нельзя. Перенесите это:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Данные отправлены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

В

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
 }
```

Получится

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Данные отправлены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
 }
```

Comment: Я как раз все операции в методе doInBackGround делаю, я новичок в андроид поэтому не очень понимаю как выносить это в бэкграунд поток, не могли бы вы подсказать как это делается

Comment: @Sanzhar Вам надо вызывать не `doInBackground`, а `execute`, как написал @katso

Comment: я уже это исправил но не помогает

Comment: @Sanzhar, обновите код в вопросе, опишите, какая теперь проблема.

Comment: все обновил код

Comment: @Sanzhar, обновил ответ :)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метод [task.execute()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...))

Comment: использую, но проблема не решается к сожалению